# System.ArgumentNullException in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#

```
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);
```

when I run this, I am getting the following error.

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in mscorlib.dll An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Value cannot be null.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Environment Variable OUTPUT_PATH is not set.

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH")
```

This statement is returning null.

Please check environment variables to confirm if path is correctly set or not. 
If path is there, then there may be access privilege issue.  Your code may not have permissions to read the environment variable.

Comment: Thanks Manoj.how to set environment variable. kindly let me know.

Comment: [link](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/) please refer this for more details.

Comment: If you don't know how to set an environment variable, why are you trying to use one?

Comment: @Amy i guess he came across it on hackerrank, they have this template code you need to complete challenges with that. he looks like a very beginner in c#